# Jenkins username with password credentials

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

Is there a way I can get only the username or the password in a job when I created it by the window:

[image]

Can I pass just the password value in a job?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a credential that is Secret Text, populate the text with the password, then expose it as an environmental variable via a binding.  The [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) can do this for you.

Comment: Credentials Binding Plugin doesn't do that yet, although there are issues submitted for that.  The https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin will, but it doesn't bind to credentials.  Sounds like you want a combination of the two.

Comment: Yes, I had reached there, the point is that we are thinking in a production enviroment where the administrator have no way to know the passwords, I have reached closer until the point where there is a folder (cloudbees folder plugin) where you can get just grants and after, can run builds using passwords that you don't even know and there is no way to know it, you just should know which password should you use. If bind parameter should do it, that could satisfy our needs

Comment: By the way the Workflow block step `withCredentials` _does_ automatically mask passwords “leaked” to the log within its scope. For freestyle projects, this feature is pending [JENKINS-24805](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24805).